# Aligning equations in a beautiful way

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

This is my code:

```
\begin{alignat*}{5}
& \mathrm{B}   &&{}+ \mathrm{R} &&{}\cdot \mathrm{t}_1 &&{}= \mathrm{R}_{\mathrm{max}}&&{}\cdot \mathrm{t}_1\\ 
&2\mathrm{MiB} &&{}+ 4\MiBs     &&{}\cdot \mathrm{t}_1 &&{}= 20\MiBs                  &&{}\cdot \mathrm{t}_1\\
&              &&{}             &&{}      \mathrm{t}_1 &&{}= 0,125\mathrm{s}          &&{}
\end{alignat*}
```

The result looks like this: 
[image: imgur]

Now I want the B, the R and the R_max in the first line to be centered above whats underneath. Additionally, I want the t_1 in the last line to be aligned with the other t_1s in the lines above. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I of course should do that, but unfortunately, I am very new to LaTeX and I use the corporate-design-packages of my university to take care of all the things you have to do at the start of every latex document. I don't know how to do these things without the packages I use and that you, of course, don't have. I do hope, though, that the image I included will give you an idea of what I try to accomplish. Also, please excuse my possibly bad english.

Comment: Related: [Question about correct typesetting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6145/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to align the content as desired is to use a `\makebox` to center the text in the desired amount of space:

[image]

### Notes:

- I would highly recommend you use [the `siunitx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) as well for typesetting anything with units.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newcommand*{\MiB}{\mathrm{MiB}}%
\newcommand*{\MiBs}{\frac{\mathrm{MiB}}{\mathrm{s}}}%

\newcommand*{\MyCenter}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{$#1$}]{$#2$}}


\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
  &\MyCenter{\MiB}{B} &&{}+ \MyCenter{4\MiBs}{R} &{}\cdot t_1 &{}= \MyCenter{20\MiBs}{R_{\max}} &&{}\cdot t_1\\ 
  &2\MiB              &&{}+ 4\MiBs               &{}\cdot t_1 &{}= 20\MiBs                      &&{}\cdot t_1\\
  &                   &&{}                       &        t_1 &{}= \SI{0,125}{\second} 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place the equations in an array, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays

For instance

```
\begin{matrix}
  -1 & 3 \\
  2 & -4
 \end{matrix}
 =
 \begin{matrix*}[r]
  -1 & 3 \\
  2 & -4
 \end{matrix*}
```

will produce

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}

 1 & 2 & 3  \ \

 6 & 7 & 8 

\end{tabular}
```

You will get

```
1   2   3 

6   7   8
```

so you can write down B,R and R_max in the first line as you said and want and others in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses an `array` environment to align the various terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{c @{} >{{}}c<{{}} c >{{}}c<{{}} l @{{}={}} c @{} >{{}}c<{{}} l}
\mathrm{B} & + & \mathrm{R} & \cdot & \mathrm{t}_1 & \mathrm{R}_{\mathrm{max}} & \cdot & \mathrm{t}_1\\[1.5ex]
2\,\mathrm{MiB} & + & 4\, \dfrac{\mathrm{MiB}}{\mathrm{s}} & \cdot & \mathrm{t}_1 & 20 \,\dfrac{\mathrm{MiB}}{\mathrm{s}} & \cdot & \mathrm{t}_1\\[2ex]
& & & & \mathrm{t}_1 & 0{,}125\mathrm{s}\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```